# Mapping data constructors to types

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I'm creating an application that allows an admin to build a form, which a user can fill out. Questions can be of different types. Each kind of question corresponds to a type of response data.

Is it possible to encode this at the type level? How would you organize this?

```
data QuestionType = EmailText | PlainText | Numeric

-- this doesn't have any response information, it's the metadata
-- about the question itself.
data Question = { id :: ID, label :: Text, questionType :: QuestionType }

data Answer = { questionID :: ID, response :: Response }

-- I would like to map those question types to different response types
data Response = ???
-- EmailText => Text
-- PlainText => Text
-- Numeric   => Int
```

I've thought about Type Families, which would work perfectly except that I want to map from different data constructors to different types, and type families would require separate types for each one.

This would be a good fit for a single ADT, with the response information included in each constructor, but I need to be able to deal with question types independently from responses.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've not completely understood what you exactly want, but maybe this can be a starting point:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs #-}

data Response (qt :: QuestionType) where
  RPlainText :: Text -> Response PlainText
  REmailText :: Text -> Response EmailText
  RNumeric :: Int -> Response Numeric

data Answer qt = Answer {questionID :: ID, response :: Response qt}
```

If you do not want the `qt` argument in `Answer qt`, you probably need existential types to hide that, but at that point you'll probably want to link it with the questions somehow.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess If you have a value `example :: Answer EmailText` you know (and the compiler knows!) that `example` was built from the `REmailText` constructor. Other constructors will produce different types, making GHC complain. Even trying to pattern match other constructors will cause errors from GHC, since that match can never happen.

Comment: Very cool. This prevents me from ever making a list of answers though right?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess If you have answers of different types, you can not put them in the same list, unless you use existential types -- but at that point you are discarding the type information we have just added. The point is: how would you exactly link questions to answers, inside types? If you made a list of (fake syntax) `exists qt. (Question qt, Answer qt)` you lose information about what type of question is (which you can recover at runtime, though), but you preserve enough type information to state that question and answer are compatible. If you instead use two lists, this is lost.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess It prevents you from making one list in the naive way -- but it doesn't prevent you from making three.

Answer (score 1):

Having types depend on values is exactly what *dependent types* are for. Unfortunately, Haskell doesn't have dependent types. However, you can use a sum type to capture the possible response types:

```
data Response = ResponseText Text | ResponseInt Int
```